# apt-get duplicate sources.list entry for google-chrome (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, google-chrome, ubuntu-11.10

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

This is the only line in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the text "google" or "chrome" in it:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Sometimes (not always) when I run `apt-get update`, I get these warnings at the end of the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

If I run `apt-get update` again immediately after receiving these warnings, they don't show up the second time (or third time, etc...). But then the warnings always come back eventually.

In any case, installing/updating `google-chrome` works fine, but those warnings are annoying (and since I skim over them now, I may inadvertently miss some more important warning if one ever comes up).

Any way to get rid of these warnings permanently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you installed chrome it most likely added a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` named `google-chrome.list`. You should remove the line you manually added, and just keep the file that is in there, which is what the chrome package uses.

Comment: That fixed it thanks! Will mark this accepted when I can in 8 minutes :). Any idea why the warnings only showed up part of the time?

Comment: Well I guess you manually added the line the first time without error, then installed the package, and then started seeing errors after chrome got installed, since it includes that file.

Comment: Yes, but after running apt-get a second time in a row, I wouldn't get errors the second time. Not that important, though. Problem solved is the important part!

Comment: Hrm, I don't have a good answer for that.

Comment: OK the other problem I found its google-chrome.list with google.list files in same directory (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`). To solve it just remove both `google.list` + `google.list.save` files and leave `google-chrome.list` + `google-chrome.list.save` files.